# How to convert an image to base64 in GAE php

Tags: php, html, image, google-app-engine, base64

as file_open_contents() is disabled in GAE php.
Any effective way to convert a image file (say png / jpg) and display image in dataurl to hide the filename and path

Comment: [string base64_encode ( string $data )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

Comment: You should be able to file_open_contents both local and GCS files on GAE. Otherwise, base64_encode(file_get_contents('gs://<bucket>/<file>')) should work in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this :

HTML :

```
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" multiple="multiple">
```

Javascript  :

```
 $("#fileToUpload").change(function(event) {

          $.each(event.target.files, function(index, file) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function(event) {  
              object = {};
              object.filename = file.name;
              object.data = event.target.result;
              files.push(object);
              datasrc = event.target.result;

                var inlineImgD = "<img src="+datasrc+">";
              };  
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          });

        });
```